# When scrolling in java the view gets distorted

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I've added a JPanel to a JScrollPane.

The JPanel has a lot of elements in there such as lables, panels buttons etc. When I scroll, the view gets distorted and i'm not sure why as i've doubled checked the code. What causes this? Is there supposed to be some repaint taking place?

[image]

```
    pgLaPanel pnlMain = new pgLaPanel();
              pnlMain.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pnlMain, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
              pnlMain.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1250,765));
              pnlMain.add(pnlTop);
              //pnlTop.setVisible(true);
              pnlMain.add(pnlLow);
              pnlLow.setVisible(true);

    JPanel pnlLadder = new JPanel((LayoutManager) new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
           pnlLadder.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pnlLadder, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
           pnlLadder.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
           pnlLadder.add(pnlTitle);
           pnlLadder.add(pnl1n2);
           pnlLadder.add(pnl3n4);
           pnlLadder.add(pnl5n6);
           pnlLadder.add(pnl7n8);
           pnlLadder.add(pnl9n10);
           pnlLadder.add(pnl11n12);
           pnlLadder.add(pnl13n14);
           pnlLadder.add(pnl15n16);
           pnlLadder.add(pnl17n18);
           pnlLadder.add(pnl19n20);
           pnlLadder.add(pnl21n22);
           pnlLadder.add(pnl23n24);
           pnlLadder.add(pnl25n26);
           pnlLadder.add(pnl27n28);
           pnlLadder.add(pnl29n30);
           pnlLadder.add(pnlButtons);


    final JScrollPane scrlLadder = new JScrollPane();
                      scrlLadder.setViewportView(pnlLadder);
                      scrlLadder.setFont(pgMnCore.useFont); 
                      scrlLadder.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));

    scrlLadder.setVisible(false);

    pnlMain.add(scrlLadder);
```

Comment: `"i'm not sure why as i've doubled checked the code"` -- but we can't. :(

Comment: This may be a custom painting issue, but unless you provide a a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, it's all just guess work. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I've added some of the code. There's a lot of repetitive code so doesn't make sense to post it all but what i posted gives you and idea of what i'm up to. thanks!

Comment: @iron You and I have a distinct difference in opinion on what a "runnable example" is.  If it can't be compiled or executed, it's not a runnable example.  What's `pgLaPanel`?

Comment: There's just a lot of lines that it wouldn't fit (i'm working on breaking it up into different classes. pgLaPanel is just a extended panel that has a background image

Comment: *" pgLaPanel is just a extended panel that has a background image"* - If you've not implemented the painting correctly that could be your problem

Comment: Hmmm Ok i'll look into that actually, thanks for pointer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pnlLadder.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
....
scrlLadder.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
```

I'm guessing the problem is the transparent background. This is easy to verify, just get rid of the setBackground(...) statements.

Check out [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for the probable problem and a couple of solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it definitely has something do with transparency issues as I eliminated the problem after setting every background to black. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: I'm think required to override RepaintManager#addDirtyRegion for JViewport and to set JViewport#setScrollMode